# Getting Attribute Error while creating a class to fetch weather data in python

Tags: python, json, api, openweathermap

It was working fine when i executed this method directly but i am getting error when i decided to create a class that would get weather data for me.

'''

```
import urllib.request
import json
class weather:

    def __init__(self, city, key, URL):
        self.city = city
        self.key = key
        self.URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="


    def getTemprature(self,a):
        fullURL = str(self.URL+self.city+"&appid="+self.key)
        data = urllib.request.urlopen(fullURL).read()
        temp = float(json.loads(data)["main"]["temp"])
        return temp

city="New Delhi" #default city
apiKey = "54df40e238084fbf095d3540271e48a0"
print(weather.getTemprature(city,apiKey))
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your getTemprature function, you only need the parameter 'self'. You should pass city, apiKey to the initializer when creating a weather object, not to the getTemprature function.

```
import urllib.request
import json
class weather:
    def __init__(self, city, key, URL):
        self.city = city
        self.key = key
        self.URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="

    def getTemprature(self):
        fullURL = str(self.URL+self.city+"&appid="+self.key)
        data = urllib.request.urlopen(fullURL).read()
        temp = float(json.loads(data)["main"]["temp"])
        return temp

city="New Delhi" #default city
apiKey = "54df40e238084fbf095d3540271e48a0"

weatherNewDelhi = weather(city, apiKey)
print(weatherNewDelhi.getTemprature())
```

Output:

```
308.15
```

Comment: No bro I passed that extra param myself, otherwise it raised another error stating "expected 1 param but 2 were passed"

Comment: In your original code, weather.getTemprature(city, apiKey) is incorrect because you aren't using the class initializer to create the weather object. You need to create a weather object by writing weather(city, apiKey) at some point, then calling the getTemprature() function on that object.